# xml nillable validation in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd-1.0

Sample xml to play with

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:element name="UsersList">
    <xs:complexType>    
   <xs:sequence>    
        <xs:element ref="User" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  
   <xs:element name="User">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element ref="Name" />
   <xs:element ref="BirthTime" />
   </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
  
 
   <xs:element name = "Name">
    <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base = "xs:string">
    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
    </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
 </xs:element>

   <xs:element name="BirthTime">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:pattern value="(0[0-9]|[1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
   
 </xs:schema>
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<UsersList>
  <User>
    <Name>sam</Name>
    <BirthTime></BirthTime>
  </User>
  <User>
    <Name>wit</Name>
    <BirthTime></BirthTime>
  </User>
</UsersList>
```

I want the birth time should allow empty value or value with HH:MM format. for HH:MM format i already manged but unable to make it to accept empty or null values. I even tried with nillable="true". but no hope. is there anyway to achieve this please

Comment: I have added an alternative answer to the cited duplicate.

Comment: this one helped me  http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_union.asp